# How to read ascii chars to int variables from file

Tags: java, ascii

I've made a java class *Levels* for a game I'm making. To make it quick to read and make the code simple, the data is in ascii character. The problem is that the class doesn't seem to execute. Could this work with some modification?

This is how i call it:

```
class G
    {        
        /* Variables */

        public G()
            {
                addKeyListener(new keys());
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
                setFocusable(true);
                Levels l = new Levels(1);
                System.out.print(l.blocks);

            }
        /* Code */
    }
```

And this is the class.

```
class Levels
    {
        int blocks, bl;
        int[] alt, bgc, gc;
        private int k;

        public Levels(int level)
             {
                try
                    {
                        FileInputStream levelfile = new FileInputStream("levels/level/" + level + ".lvl");
                        Scanner ls = new Scanner(levelfile);
                        this.bl=((int)ls.nextByte())-32;
                        this.blocks=(int)ls.nextByte()-32;
                        for(k=0; k<6; k++)
                            {
                                this.bgc[k]=((int)ls.nextByte()-32)*2;
                            }
                        for(k=0; k<6; k++)
                            {
                                this.gc[k]=((int)ls.nextByte()-32)*2;
                            }
                        for(k=0; k<blocks; k++)
                            {
                                this.bgc[k]=((int)ls.nextByte()-32)*2;
                            }
                    }
                catch(FileNotFoundException error)
                    {
                        System.out.print("Level not found..." + error);
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: It is hard to imagine what you are doing from the code. Can you produce a simple description of the file format you would like?

Comment: As I see he tries to save/load state of  `int blocks, bl;        int[] alt, bgc, gc;` fields.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` for such purposes. It will solve a lot of your problems with your idea.

**UPD:** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html

**UPD-2** I do not suggest you reading your text file using `DataInputStream`. I suggest do not use textual (`ascii`) file representation for your purposes.

**UPD-3** Ok. If you want still read/write text files, then several advices.
1) According to your read-file code, you don't use any delimiters between written values. Isn't it? Simplest way is using carriage return, i.e. write each value on a new line.

2) In this case it will be probably more convenient to read such file using `BufferedReader`:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream('... your path ...');
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String line;

line = br.readLine();
this.bl = Integer.parseInt(line);

line = br.readLine();
this.blocks= Integer.parseInt(line);

... and so on

br.close();
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I agree, but I don't suggest to read such way text file. I suggest not to use text files, but write/read all needed values using `DataStream`-s.

Comment: I believe he wants to be able to edit/visualise his levels without having to write tools to do that.  Much easier to read a text file in an editor.

Comment: Well, ok. What about my third suggestion? (UPD-3) :)